# Server doest recognize array

Tags: arrays, server

Using vb.net.
I want to put this code on server(module)

```
 Sub sufflePlayers()

        Dim playersArray(3) As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To 3
            playersArray(i) = i
        Next
        Dim MyRandomArray = playersArray.OrderBy(Function() rnd.Next()).ToArray()

    End Sub
```

But it throw an error "orderby is not member of system.array"
It also happened with count.
It not recognize playersArray as array but at something else.
when i put point , it give me an options like BinarySearch and SyncRoot
now its happened just in the module server program. in the client form its not throw an error

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework is the project using? The [Enumerable.OrderBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) is in the System.Linq namespace, so try adding `Imports System.Linq`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton im using vb2008 so i think its 3.5(where i can find it ?) however i dont have linq option in the import system. declare. im using the same vb version in the client program and there it work.

Comment: What do you mean by "server"? If it's a computer, does it have .NET Framework 3.5 installed? (Instructions if needed: [Install the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 10, Windows 8.1, and Windows 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10)).

Comment: Ah, you might need to add a reference to System.Core.dll to the project to be able to use System.Linq: [How to Add References to Your Visual Studio Project](https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-add-references-to-your-visual-studio-projec/).

Comment: @AndrewMorton ok. first of all the linq dll indeed solve the problem. thank you very much. i have framework 3.5 . when i say server i mean its a server/client program.only on the server  side i had this problem. strange...